# Unable to InsertModelSDF into World from model plugin (Bug or Error??)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm working on a ModelPlugin that spawns a new model and adjusts the position of the model based on the other model's position. To do this i create an sdf::SDF from string and spawn it with the function world->InsertModelSDF(modelSDF).
The function looks like this:

```
std::string sensor_pose_as = pose3dToString(this->link_pose);
    sdf::SDF modelSDF;
    modelSDF.SetFromString(
    "<sdf version='1.6'>\
    <model name='Particle_"+this->parent_save_name_+"'>\
    <link name='link_"+this->particle_link_name_+"'>\
      <pose frame=''>"+sensor_pose_as+"</pose>\
      <gravity>0</gravity>\
      <self_collide>0</self_collide>\
      <kinematic>0</kinematic>\
      <visual name='visual_0'>\
        <pose>"+std::to_string(this->p_range)+" 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>\
        <geometry>\
          <box>\
            <size>"+std::to_string(p_size)+" "+std::to_string(p_size)+" 0.001</size>\
          </box>\
        </geometry>\
        <material>\
          <lighting>0</lighting>\
          <script>\
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>\
            <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>\
          </script>\
        </material>\
        <transparency>"+std::to_string(this->p_transparency_)+"</transparency>\
        <cast_shadows>0</cast_shadows>\
      </visual>\
    </link>\
    <static>0</static>\
    </model>\
    </sdf>");
    sdf::ElementPtr model = modelSDF.Root()->GetElement("model");
    
    for(int i=1; i<=this->num_particles; i++)
    {
            //do other stuff
    }

    ROS_INFO("Insert Model into World");
    this->model_ = model;
    this->world_->InsertModelSDF(modelSDF);
    //this->parent_->GetWorld()->InsertModelString(modelSDF.ToString());

    common::Time::MSleep(1000);
    ROS_INFO("Setting Pose");
    math::Pose p = math::Pose(this->link_pose);
    this->particle_model_ = this->parent_->GetWorld()->GetModel("Particle_"+this->parent_save_name_);

    ROS_INFO("2 %s",this->particle_model_->GetName().c_str());
    this->particle_model_->SetLinkWorldPose(p, this->particle_link_name_);
    ROS_INFO("Particle Model loaded properly");
```

I used the exact same function in a SensorPlugin and it worked perfectly. When i debugged the programm this

```
this->particle_model_ = this->parent_->GetWorld()->GetModel("Particle_"+this->parent_save_name_);
```

always return NULL.
Already checked the modelSDF Variable in a extern file and it's okay. Don't know if its a bug since it worked perfectly in my other Plugin.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21028/unable-to-insertmodelsdf-into-world-from-model-plugin--(bug-or-error??)/) by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 350 on 2018-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sensor plugins run in a separate thread, so when you sleep your plugin for a second, the physics thread is taking care of inserting the model. Model plugins on the other hand run in the physics thread, so when you sleep, you're halting even the code which should be processing the model insertion.

There are several ways to work around this, you could publish a factory message from a different thread and block only that thread until the model is inserted, you can get the model on a later callback, or maybe pause the world, step it a few times and then unpause it... Just some ideas ;)

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on 2018-11-20**:
Thanks, guess this will fix my problem and i learned something new :). Unfortunately i will not be able to check it until next week probably. Anyway thanks a lot and have a nice week.